# How to access a button which changes states

Tags: python, css, selenium

I have a button which has two states - enabled and disabled

Enabled State:
`<button type="button" class="btt-download-csv site-toolbar-menu-button icon-download no-icon-margins ng-isolate-scope" title="Download CSV" rc-download-csv="" current-segment-path="all" ng-disabled="noCustomers || loadingCustomers" ng-show="!deleteModeEnabled"></button>`

Disabled State:
`<button type="button" class="btt-download-csv site-toolbar-menu-button icon-download no-icon-margins ng-isolate-scope" title="Download CSV" rc-download-csv="" current-segment-path="all" ng-disabled="noCustomers || loadingCustomers" ng-show="!deleteModeEnabled" disabled=""></button>`

Notice a `disabled=""` word by the end of the code. How do I specify that I want to click on a button that is NOT disabled?

I use the following css selector but it does not care about state of the button:

```
"button.btt-download-csv.site-toolbar-menu-button.icon-download.no-icon-margins.ng-isolate-scope"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `css_selector` to locate an element without specific attribute

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[title="Download CSV"]:not([disabled])')
```

Or with `xpath`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@title="Download CSV"][not(@disabled)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable a button, just add the attribute `disabled`.

**Normal button:** `<button type="button"></button>`

**Access this button with css:** `button {}`

**Disabled button:** `<button type="button" disabled></button>`

**Access this button with css:** `button[disabled] {}`